# Sum a string column that contains values and text

Tags: powerbi, dax, calculated-columns

I want to use a DAX formula to sum the hours spent but the column has string values which is used in other parts of the PowerBI report.

Example below shows how the data comes from the SQL server, the data is from a form on a system where each question asked will be on a separate row.

| ANSWER_NO | ANSWER |
| --- | --- |
| HOURS_SPENT | 37 |
| HOURS_SPENT | 5 |
| SOLD | Yes |
| FormEndDate | 06-MAR-2023 |

The formula I have tired is:

```
Sum of hours =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( FACT_FORMS_ANSWERS[ANSWER] ),
    FILTER (
        FACT_FORMS_ANSWERS,
        FACT_FORMS_ANSWERS[ANSWER_NO] = "HOURS_SPENT"
    )
)
```

This doesn't work as Answer column is not a value, but I can't use Value() function as I am not using a calculated column. Is there a solution to this in DAX?

I have tired this also bring a similar error message:

[image: Sumx error message]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to sum a columns mixing with numbers in text format and also text value in Power bI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75698779/how-to-sum-a-columns-mixing-with-numbers-in-text-format-and-also-text-value-in-p)

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
Sum of hours = 
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        FACT_FORMS_ANSWERS,
        FACT_FORMS_ANSWERS[ANSWER_NO] = "HOURS_SPENT"
    ),
    VALUE(FACT_FORMS_ANSWERS[ANSWER])
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the support Peter however it runs into the same problem.

It brings an error says 'Couldn't load the data for this visual'
MdxScript(Model)(37,5) Calculation error in measure 'NAme of Measure' Cannot convert value 'Ongoing' of type Text to type Number.

Comment: What problem? As you can see from my screenshot it's working properly. Please post your error message.

Comment: Apologies see above editted comment

Comment: You filter by FCG_HOURS and the corresponding ANSWER is "Ongoing"? Of cause you can't convert this to a number.  SUMX() is an iterator function that evaluates row by row just like a calculated column, so VALUE() will work if all non-convertible strings are filtered out first.