# how to sum a columns mixing with numbers in text format and also text value in Power bI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I would like to sum up a column where contains numbers and text values, please note that the numbers are also in text format too.

### For example:
[Column Name]

1111

2222

3333

'----'

4444

5555

I want to add up 1111+2222+3333+4444+5555

Here is the Measure that I did

Measure = calculate(sum([column name]),filter([Table name], not contains([Table name],[Column Name], "---")))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are:

```
Sum Column = 
SUMX(
    FILTER(
        'Table',
        'Table'[Column] <> "----"
    ),
    VALUE('Table'[Column])
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help, however, it doesn't work, still getting errors :(

Comment: As you can see from my screenshot the measure is working properly. What's your error message? Note that the text in your sample has 4 dashes "----", while your measure had 3 only.